# CentOS 7 kickstart - Skip media check during unattended installation?

Tags: linux, centos7, kickstart

Is there any way to skip the media check screen during unattended text-mode installations of CentOS 7?

I usually install using the minimal ISO, and I've noticed that I need to press ESC once or twice to get out of the ISO's media check.

I don't have `mediacheck` or `rd.live.check` specified anywhere in my kickstart file.

Comment: `rd.live.check` would appear on the boot command line, rather than in the kickstart.

Comment: and the media check happens before the kickstart is even loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CentOS ISO images include `rd.live.check` as a boot command line option. If you haven't rolled your own images, or manually removed this each time you boot, then the media check will occur.

The following appears when booting the CentOS 7.2.1511 netinstall image:

[image: CentOS 7 boot: Test this media and install CentOS 7]
[image: CentOS 7 boot: Test this media and install CentOS 7: Kernel command line]

To resolve the problem, tap your up arrow key to select "Install CentOS 7" instead of "Test this media & install CentOS 7".

[image: CentOS 7 Boot: Install CentOS 7]
[image: CentOS 7 Boot: Install CentOS 7: Kernel command line]

Comment: That's heavy-handed, no?

Comment: Running the media check by default has been the thing to do ever since recordable CD-ROMs were a thing. Lots of them were bad, and you didn't want to find out halfway through an installation that you had a coaster.

Comment: Someone needs to retire that antiquated idea now - most installs are network/cloud now, and media-check takes way longer than a failed install would take, for nothing - there's no "media" to check...

Comment: @cnd Lots of installs take place on a USB stick now, which probably still needs a media check, but I certainly wouldn't want to let it do a media check when doing an installation over iLO with the ISO on my workstation and the server halfway around the world... Unfortunately the default is still to test media in RHEL 8.